# Converting Case statement, Filter from t-SQL query to DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a problem converting below t-sql query into DAX.

**Overview -**  There are two sample tables - Table1 and Table2 with below schema

Table1 (ID varchar(20),Name varchar(30))

Table2 (CapID varchar(20),CAPName varchar(30), CapID_Final varchar(20))

**Please note :** There exists one to many relationship between above tables : [ID] in Table2 with [CapID] in Table1

I am trying to derive CapID_Final column in table2 based on conditions as per my t-SQL query in below which works perfectly fine -

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN [CapID] like 'CA%' and [CAPName]='x12345-Sample' 
       and [CapID] not in(select [ID] from Table1 where Name='x12345-Sample')
       THEN 'Undefined_Cap_1'

       WHEN [CapID] like 'CA%' and [CAPName]='z12345-Sample' 
       and [CapID] not in(select [ID] from Table1 where Name='z12345-Sample')
       THEN 'Undefined_Cap_2'

       WHEN [CapID] like 'CA%' and [CAPName]='a123-Sample' 
       and [CapID] not in(select [ID] from Table1 where Name='a123-Sample')
       THEN 'Undefined'

       ELSE [CapID]

   END AS [CapID_Final] from Table2
```

However, I want the same derivation for CapID_Final column in Power BI in a calculated column using DAX.

So far, I have tried below code - but it returns "Undefined" for even matched conditions -

```
CapID_Final = 
IF(LEFT(Table2[CapID],2)="CA" && Table2[CAPName]="z12345-Sample" && 
NOT 
(COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        Table1,CONTAINS(Table1,Table1[ID],Table2[CapID])
    )
) > 0),"Undefined_Cap_1","Undefined"
)
```

I am not familiar with DAX, however I tried and couldn't figure it out.
Could you please let me know how to convert my sql query to equivalent DAX in Power BI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SWITCH` is basically the equivalent of a `CASE` clause here:

```
CapID_Final =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    LEFT ( Table2[CapID], 2 ) = "CA"
        && Table2[CAPName] = "x12345-Sample"
        && NOT (
            Table2[CapID]
                IN CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( Table1[ID] ), Table1[Name] = "x12345-Sample" )
        ), "Undefined_Cap_1",
    LEFT ( Table2[CapID], 2 ) = "CA"
        && Table2[CAPName] = "z12345-Sample"
        && NOT (
            Table2[CapID]
                IN CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( Table1[ID] ), Table1[Name] = "z12345-Sample" )
        ), "Undefined_Cap_2",
    LEFT ( Table2[CapID], 2 ) = "CA"
        && Table2[CAPName] = "a12345-Sample"
        && NOT (
            Table2[CapID]
                IN CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( Table1[ID] ), Table1[Name] = "a12345-Sample" )
        ), "Undefined",
    Table1[CapID]
)
```

You might even be able to refactor it a bit to be more code efficient. Assuming I didn't make any logic mistakes:

```
CapID_Final =
VAR IDs =
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( Table1[ID] ), Table1[Name] = Table2[CAPName] )
RETURN
    IF (
        LEFT ( Table2[CapID], 2 ) = "CA"
            && NOT ( Table2[CapID] IN IDs ),
        SWITCH (
            Table2[CAPName],
            "x12345-Sample", "Undefined_Cap_1",
            "z12345-Sample", "Undefined_Cap_2",
            "a12345-Sample", "Undefined"
        ),
        Table1[CapID]
    )
```

Comment: Hi Alexis, thanks a lot..  First query works fine as I validated the result of CAPID_FInal.. However, it is resulting circular dependency while I am trying to establish relationship between ID in Table1 with CAPID_Final in Table2. Could you suggest, what should I do it prevent it? I would like to try it in M query - however,  I am not sure how should I write logic for subquery in IF statements for the below DAX?

IN CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( Table1[ID] ), Table1[Name] = "x12345-Sample" )

Answer (score 0):

As a best-practice never use calculated column. In fact, if extensively used they slow down your model refresh and heavily increase your model weight (because they are not compressed). Instead, calculate it in your back-end database or using M Query.
Having said this, the solution to your question is very simple using a [SWITCH](https://dax.guide/SWITCH/) function:

```
SWITCH ( <Expression>, <Value>, <Result> [, <Value>, <Result> [, … ] ] [, <Else>] )
```

In your case would be as follow:

```
CapIDFinal:=
SWITCH(TRUE(),
AND(CONDITION_1_1, CONDITION_1_2), "Value if condition 1 is true",
AND(CONDITION_2_1, CONDITION_2_2), "Value if condition 2 is true",
"Value if none of above conditions is true
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Seymour. How should I write logic for subquery in IF statements for the below DAX?

IN CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( Table1[ID] ), Table1[Name] = "x12345-Sample" )

Comment: In DAX.GUIDE website you can find all the functions you need or you can open other question specifically related to other functions. This one was about how to convert a SQL CASE WHEN into DAX and the answer is using the SWITCH function